# Discord.py How can I make the bot only register the first user reaction?

Tags: python, discord.py

I have this code where when the user react the bot sends a message. But the thing is right now if the user unreact and then react again the bot will send a new message. I only want the bot to register the first time ever a user reacted with that reaction and send a message and if the user unreact and reacts again the bot dont send a message.

Do aynone know how to do that?

> Here is the code:

```
bot.event

async def on_raw_reaction_add(reaction):

if reaction.channel_id == verify_channel_id:

if str(reaction.emoji) == "✅":

verified_role = get(reaction.member.guild.roles, name = "REACTED")

await reaction.member.add_roles(verified_role)



bot.event

async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):

if payload.channel_id == 1014925506606534689:

if str(payload.emoji) == "✅":

user = bot.get_user(payload.user_id)

channel1 = bot.get_channel(1015516535223242762)

await channel1.send(f'{payload.member.mention} REACTED WITH ✅!')
```

Comment: Please fix the indentation and include a [mcve]

Comment: you can use wait_for function

Comment: You could hold the users that react to messages in a dictionary where the keys are message ids and values are sets of user ids.